# Spring Vault can't validate self-signed cert signed by self-signed CA after upgrading from Spring Boot 2.7.x -> Spring Boot 3.0.0

Tags: spring, kotlin, java-17, spring-vault

I am running Spring Boot app using a self-signed CA cert to verify Vault certificate that is signed by the self-signed CA.

This setup has worked with Spring Vault until upgrading from Spring Boot 2.7.x -> 3.0.0.
Since Spring Boot 3.0.0 required Spring Framework 6.x and hence Java 17, I've also had to upgrade `org.springframework.vault:spring-vault-core` from `2.3.2` to `3.0.0` which now supports Java 17.

I configure Spring Vault via extending `AbstractVaultConfiguration` class which requires overriding `sslConfiguration` method in this way:

```
    override fun sslConfiguration(): SslConfiguration {
        val caPemBytes = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(vaultCaPemBase64)
        val vaultCaStore = ByteArrayResource(caPemBytes)
        return SslConfiguration(
            KeyStoreConfiguration.unconfigured(),
            KeyStoreConfiguration.of(vaultCaStore, null, "pem")
        )
    }
```

Now When I run the Spring Boot application, I get a long stack trace saying

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.vault.authentication.SessionManager]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'vaultConfiguration' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'sessionManager' threw exception with message: I/O error on POST request for "https://my.vault.host/v1/auth/userpass/login/my-user-name": PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

which means that the request to connect to Vault to log in failed because of the HTTP client being unable to verify the self-signed Vault certificate.

Also I get this warning in the logs during Spring Boot app startup:
`o.s.v.c.ClientHttpRequestFactoryFactory  : VaultProperties has SSL configured but the SSL configuration must be applied outside the Vault Client to use the JDK HTTP client`

Here's the long stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://my.vault.host/v1/auth/userpass/login/my-user-name": PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.createResourceAccessException(RestTemplate.java:888) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:868) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:764) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:481) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration.sessionManager(AbstractVaultConfiguration.java:149) ~[spring-vault-core-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:257) ~[spring-core-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at com.noona.authenticationservice.config.VaultConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.sessionManager(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    ... 163 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:371) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:309) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1415) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:450) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:421) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:142) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:75) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.vault.client.RestTemplateBuilder.lambda$createTemplate$4(RestTemplateBuilder.java:239) ~[spring-vault-core-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:87) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.vault.client.VaultClients.lambda$createRestTemplate$0(VaultClients.java:117) ~[spring-vault-core-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:87) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:71) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:862) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    ... 177 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1341) ~[na:na]
    ... 203 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[na:na]
    ... 208 common frames omitted
```

My question is, what exactly is that needs to be done here to get Spring Vault to use the self-signed CA cert to verify the self-signed Vault certificate when connecting to Vault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that in newer version of spring-vault-core did not anymore include a compile-time dependency on `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient` like in the previous versions before `3.0.0`, see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.vault/spring-vault-core/2.3.2 for example.
Version `3.0.0` has optional compile-time dependency on `org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5`: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.vault/spring-vault-core/3.0.0

The reason the setup with older spring-vault-core worked was that I had other dependency pulling in the older dependency `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient`.

In order to preserve this functionality, adding dependency to `org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5` to `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` (for example version `5.2.1`) did the trick and allowed the spring-vault-core to leverage `httpclient5` as 3rd party http client as opposed to the platform default.